# rich:jQuery alternative for Primefaces 5

Tags: jsf, primefaces, richfaces

What is an alternative of Richfaces rich:jQuery element for Primefaces 5?

I know about widgets, but widgetVar attribute is applicable only for Primefaces elements, but not for simple JSF. For example, how can I write this element in Primefaces? 
`<rich:jQuery name="enableCancel" selector="#cancel" query="removeAttr('disabled');" />`
Element 'cancel' is a JSF outputLink.

What is the best way to do such things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use plain jquery. There is imo no real advantage in using this component over simple plain jquery

Comment: The most significant advantage for me it is selectors. I could write `selector="shortElementId"` or use `#{rich:clientId('shortElementId')}` and I should not declare script block explicitly. 

Primefaces provides only `#{p:component}`, but I always can write a new function for myself. 

Anyway thank you for the answer.